# Class file has wrong version 61.0, should be 52.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

I want to create a Spring Boot project on Intellij Idea and i choose Java 8 and Java 1.8 sdk but when i open the pom.xml i saw my java version is 17 !? how can it possible ?

When i run my project i see this message below and how can my jars version 6.0.7 ?;

```
java: cannot access org.springframework.http.HttpStatus
  bad class file: /C:/Users/eegee/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/6.0.7/spring-web-6.0.7.jar!/org/springframework/http/HttpStatus.class
    class file has wrong version 61.0, should be 52.0
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three things you can check or do:

1. Check the version of Spring Boot. For example, Spring Boot 3.X baseline requires Java 17.
2. Specify explicitly the required Java version in the parent `pom.xml` (and apply it to all modules as well).

   ```xml
   <properties>
       <java.version>1.8</java.version>
   </properties>
   ```
3. In case you use `maven-compiler-plugin`, you also want to check the version in its properties:

   ```xml
   <properties>
       <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
       <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
   </properties>
   ```

   Alternatively, specify it inside the plugin configuration itself:

   ```xml
   <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
   </plugin>
   ```

You can also refer to `${java.version}` across the `pom.xml` files.

Comment: I changed my spring version to 2.7.10 and my kafka version is 2.8.0 and its work ! thank mate

Answer (score -1):

If you are using JDK >17 and up-to-date libraries like Spring 6, use version 5.1.0 (Release Notes). If you are on older JDK or library, use version 4.44.0 (documentation).
[Look on it](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock#jdbctemplate)

It seems to me that ypu should use 4.44.0
It  worked for me when I corrected with problem